# MySQL Workbench: Cannot export a database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, server-administration

I am encountering a problem concerning the export of a database. 
First of all, I have to clarify that I am using **MySQL Workbench 5.2.47**. The procedure that I followed so far is the following:

1. I followed the instructions of http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/07/migrating-from-ms-sql-server-to-mysql-using-workbench-migration-wizard/ in order to create a connection with my `MSSQL DB` in order to transform it into `MySQL DB`.
2. Then I also checked that my data is imported in the database.
3. Now I want to export it into an sql file / or preferably to frm,myi,myd files in order to place them in my server.

I have tried to export them from

- Server Administration -> Data Export
- Changed already the password from the security (Users and Privileges)

but I encounter the problem

```
Dumping test (all tables)
Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\d_micha\appdata\local\temp\tmpgtwa_m.cnf"  --user=root --max_allowed_packet=1G --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --routines --events --no-data "test"

mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

Operation failed with exitcode 2
```

I don't know what I might be doing wrong and I have searched in google to find the solution, but it should be normally exported.

Any other information will be given upon request.

Thank you.

Comment: Moving around frm, MYI or MYD files is Very Bad. Every time you do it, an innocent kitten dies.

Comment: Have not used it, so can't tell you how to fix it, but it would seem the problem is that MySQL workbench is not passing your password on to the mysqldump command.

Comment: Is there a way that I could fix that?

Answer (score 28):

I've seen this issue when you don't have the `LOCK TABLES` permission. You'll see this error before the rest of the access denied errors in the log. Try disabling `LOCK TABLES` in advanced settings in the Data Export panel of the workbench.

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'%' to database 'XXX' when doing LOCK TABLES
```

Comment: For completeness, in Mysql Workbench under "Advanced option -> Other" it is possible to uncheck the "Lock-tables" flag, which is mandatory if user has no LOCK TABLE privileges

Comment: Worked for me too. In case you are struggling to find the "Advanced Options" button, it's not on the app menu, it is on the the data export tab on the top right hand side.

Comment: @DarlingtonMoyo you beautiful person

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1 - Provide correct config file to each mysqldump-call

This is more a workaround, but it will get you to the desired result. Just use the provided information to get a dump of your MySQL-Table from the CLI - basically it's just copy & paste:

As you can see from the log *mysqldump* has the parameter *--defaults-file*. This file can and will contain connection credentials, like the *password*. Apparently MySQLWorkbench is not providing the password with this file ("using password: NO").

So just create a file named database.cnf and put it somewhere to your computer (e.g. c:\temp\database.cnf) containing the credentials like this:

```
[client]
user=root
password=your-root-password
single-transaction=TRUE
host=localhost
port=3306
default-character-set=utf8
max_allowed_packet=1G
```

As this also works with any other parameter from the command line, you may also add all your other stuff like, *--single-transaction* etc.
Now take your log file entry:

```
Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\d_micha\appdata\local\temp\tmpgtwa_m.cnf"  --user=root --max_allowed_packet=1G --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --routines --events --no-data "test"
```

And replace the *--defaults-extra-file* parameter to point to your *database.cnf* - also remove the "Running:" info and every parameter you are already providing in your database.cnf:

```
mysqldump.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\temp\database.cnf" --routines --events --no-data "test"
```

Then open a Shell, go to your MySQLWorkbench-Folder and run the command, e.g:

```
cd c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\
mmysqldump.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\temp\database.cnf" --routines --events --no-data "test" > c:\Users\user\Downloads\table1.sql
```

Do not forget to route the output to a file!

Long story short: Use the CLI tool mysqldump, MySQLWorkbench is doing the same, but not the correct way.

## Solution 2 - Provide a global correct config file

*mysqldump* also reads a global config file, if it exists in one of those locations:

- C:\WINDOWS\my.ini
- C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf
- C:\my.ini
- C:\my.cnf
- c:\Program Files\MySQL\my.ini
- c:\Program Files\MySQL\my.cnf

So you can just put the information from the above edited cnf-file to one of this locations and run the mysqldump-command without the *--defaults-file*-parameter

## Solution 3 Just call mysqldump with no parameters

This is maybe the most sophisticated solution: The my.cnf will will work with any parameter that mysqldump accepts. So why don't just use this to configure your dump? Just add all parameters to your my.cnf

```
[client]
user=root
password=secretPassword
single-transaction=TRUE
host=localhost
protocol=tcp
port=3306
default-character-set=utf8
skip-triggers=TRUE
all-databases=TRUE
all-tablespaces=TRUE
```

Now run mysqldump on the shell / command line, without any parameters, and you're good:

```
cd c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\
mysqldump.exe  > c:\Users\user\Downloads\dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91640.

> Actually we can use an advanced option in Workbench to disable column statistics as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944315/1694902 - see below:
>
> 1. Go to Management/Data export
> 2. Choose the schema to export in the 'Tables to export' list
> 3. Click the 'Advanced Options...' button (top right)
> 4. Search for the option 'Other/column-statistics'
> 5. Set the value to 0
> 6. Click the 'Return' button (top right)
>
> According to the author of this post, "Unfortunately, you'll have to do that every time you start MySQL Workbench."

It's work for me, may be it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

> Operation failed with exitcode 2

also occurs with column statistic issues, which I fixed this by amending the MySQL Workbench config file `wb_admin_export.py`.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803608/cant-export-my-database-from-mysql-workbench/59982834#59982834).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after trying the most options above on MysqlWokbench 8.0.32 and listed the flow based on [The answers of the Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803608/cant-export-my-database-from-mysql-workbench/52944315#52944315)

1. Locate 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules'.
2. Create a backup of 'wb_admin_export.py' file (Replace back in any case).
3. Close the MysqlWorkbench if open.
4. Open notepad with admin privileges and open the file 'wb_admin_export.py'.
5. Search for the following line.

   **skip_column_statistics = True if get_mysqldump_version() >
   Version(8, 0, 2) and self.owner.ctrl_be.target_version < Version(8,
   0, 0) else False**
6. Keep only '**skip_column_statistics = True**' and delete the right part of the above line. (Don't keep any tabs or line comments since python code blocks recognize by tabs and just delete the right part of the code).

[image: Before file]

[image: After change]

6. Save the file, start the MySQL workbench, and try to export again.

Answer (score -4):

MySQL workbench is trying to access your database without a password (notice the `using password: NO` in the error). Surprisingly you managed to get access to the server instance. Recreate the server instance, or at least try with a newly created instance.

Comment: It is a coincidence that "using password: No" is there, since I tried to connect with my password. I have changed all the passwords in order to be able to use the database. I have tried with the password that I gave also :)

Comment: Then your (MySQL WB) server instance is certainly broken as it never provides a password. Try recreating the server instance. Any change?