# Can't export my database from mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, export, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export my database from MySQL Workbench but I get this during the export progress:

> Running: mysqldump.exe
> --defaults-file="c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\tmp2h91wa.cnf"  --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "mydb" mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
> JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')
> FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE
> SCHEMA_NAME = 'mydb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'courses';': Unknown table
> 'column_statistics' in information_schema (1109)
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 2 20:55:09 Export of
> C:\Users\user\Documents\dumps\mydb.sql has finished with 1 errors

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the new MySQL Workbench (8.x) trying to export from earlier versions of MySQL databases (5.x). I'm having the same issue and can't see a workaround within the MySQL Workbench tool. There doesn't seem to be an option to set column_statistics to 0 in the GUI. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89825.

Comment: This bug seems to be fixed in Workbench 8.0.20, at least updating Workbench on Ubuntu 20.04 removed the error for me.

Comment: I still have the problem in 8.0.26

Comment: Same problem with 8.0.28 Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In MySql Workbench version 8.0.13 do the following steps:

1. Go to Management/Data export
2. Choose the schema to export in the 'Tables to export' list
3. Click the 'Advanced Options...' button (top right)
4. Search for the option 'Other/column-statistics'
5. Set the value to 0
6. Click the 'Return' button (top right)

Now it should work. Unfortunately, you'll have to do that every time you start MySql Workbench.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It worked for me.  It is also referenced on the [MySQL bug tracker](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91640).

Comment: My Workbench doesn't have this option, maybe because the production database it's on 5.x version and I'm using 8.x. Is there some way to activate something like a compatibility mode between mysqldump.exe 8.x and MySQL Server 5.x?

Comment: It seems this is not an option in the latest versions. The bug tracker issue that ThatGuyRob mentions says that they added a pop-up warning with instructions on how to fix it, which is described in Artem's answer.

Comment: As explained in [this other MySQL bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94294), this issue for WorkBench 8.0.14 & 8.0.15 will be fixed in version 8.0.16

Comment: As described by @Veve it is a not fixed issue, In Mac my solution was to downgrade the WorkBench to version v.6.3.10 and it works ok, I hoe this help.

Comment: This is another workaround, if you don't see the "Other/column statistics" menu item: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121256/914352

Comment: As another workaround for new versions of Workbench, you can apply this patch easily https://serverfault.com/a/1015459

Answer (score 66):

To summarize what I did from the helpful comments of [@JustinLaureno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803608/cant-export-my-database-from-mysql-workbench#58773247) and [@Mohd.Shaizad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803608/cant-export-my-database-from-mysql-workbench#58516553), tested on MySQL Workbench 8.0.18:

- Navigate to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules`
- Edit the file `wb_admin_export.py` (you need admin permissions for this)
- amend the line:

```py
skip_column_statistics = True if get_mysqldump_version() > Version(8, 0, 2) and self.owner.ctrl_be.target_version < Version(8, 0, 0) else False
```

- to:

```py
skip_column_statistics = True
```

- ***DO NOT*** add inline comments or it won't work!

```py
 skip_column_statistics = True # This won't work
```

- Restart MySQL Workbench
- Perform the export

Comment: mine doesnt have a `skip_column_statistics` im using MySql workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: Great, now how would we do this on mac? Where can we find that file.... anyone know?

Comment: fixed my problem working on Workbench version 8.0.23 with Windows.

Comment: worked for me.
I'm using mysql workbench 8.0.26 with ubuntu 20.04.
target DB mysql version 10.1.48

Comment: This worked for me but for a different reason - adding the path also worked but I then got an error regarding a variable tz=utc that I could not work around. I switched to the default mysqld.exe in workbench and made the config change and no longer get this error

Answer (score 56):

Also ran into this problem.
Decided as follows:
In the Workbench menu, go to:

*Edit - Preferences - Administration*

In the field "*Path to mysqldump Tool*", prescribe the path to **mysqldump.exe**, in my case "*C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe*", click OK.

After that, the error no longer appeared.

Comment: This is now the correct answer based on the fact that it matches the instructions that were added to the pop-up warning you get when trying to do an export, which was added in MySQL Workbench 8.0.13.

Comment: For me this was in 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe' However, this did not fix my error.

Comment: this fixed the error for me, path is the location where you have installed "mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe"

Comment: awesome solution

Comment: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe` didnt work for me. Found the solution @JeremyTaylor ?

Answer (score 36):

It is due to a flag that is by default "enabled" in mysqldump 8.

That can be disabled by adding `--column-statistics=0`.

Syntax :

```
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --host=<server> --user <user> --password <securepass>
```

For more info please go to [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_column-statistics).

To disable column statistics by default, you can add:

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

to a MySQL config file, such as `/etc/my.cnf` or `~/.my.cnf`.

Comment: Life saver! Thanks :)

Comment: This is better solution when you're using `mysqldump` to backup a database and the error pops up.

Answer (score 16):

Bug still in Workbench 8.0.16.

Fix:

You can edit wb_admin_export.py under modules in the workbench program directory. Search for "skip_column_statistics = True" (you will find a conditional, don't worry), comment that line and add a line "skip_column_statistics = True" (without a conditional).

The required parameter will now be always added.

Comment: This worked for me in version 8.0.22, but very surprisingly it only worked when I edited the existing line itself. When I made a duplicate and edited the duplicate (with the original one commented), Workbench wasn't displaying anything in the Navigator (left sidebar). Odd behavior, nothing helped except editing the original line. I'm suspecting that Workbench parses its own .py files for some reason and chokes when it finds its variables in an unexpected way, even if that's in a comment.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue 5 minutes ago.

I fixed it by adding in my `mysqldump` command `--column-statistics=0`. 
Do it and it should work.

In my case it's a phing task but you should get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I too had the same problem.. I am able to resolve this Issue by disabling the column-statistics in the advanced options of the MySQL Workbench Data Export.

1: Click on the advanced options:
[image]

2: In the other section for the column-statistics remove TRUE and set it to 0 to disable it.
[image]

Now Return and Export the Data.
Thank You

Answer (score 8):

I found this condition in `wb_admin_export.py` instead of a commented `--column-statistics=0`. you can remove the `else False` condition, or change it to `else True`.

```
skip_column_statistics = True if get_mysqldump_version() > Version(8,
0, 2) and self.owner.ctrl_be.target_version < Version(8, 0, 0) else
True
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

edit the workbench preferences:
Edit -> Preferences -> Administration

in the property "Path to mysqldump Tool" place the path of your mysqldump.exe
It is usually found in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe"

Answer (score 4):

From **Mysql-workbench version 8.0.14** you don't have the option to disable **column-statistics**.

But you have an option to do it by **enabling delete-master-logs:**
[Mysql-workbench version 8.0.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phtXs.png)

- **--delete-master-logs** has the same effect as the **"RESET MASTER"** SQL command
- **RESET MASTER** deletes all binary log files listed in the index file, resets the binary log index file to be empty, and creates a new binary log file. This statement is intended to be used only when the master is started for the first time.

Comment: Running: mysqldump --defaults-file="/tmp/tmp5c5ww33n/extraparams.cnf"  --host=x.x.x.x --port=3307 --default-character-set=utf8 --user=admin --protocol=tcp --delete-master-logs=TRUE --skip-triggers "fedena"
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ..................
Operation failed with exitcode 2
Export of b'/home/sanaulla/dumps/Dump20210331.sql' has finished with 1 errors

Comment: This one helped me. Thanks

Comment: This didn't work for me since my user does not have the right privileges. Still, it is worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules` and open this file `wb_admin_export.py` and uncomment "`--column-statistics=0`" then Restart the workbench

Comment: can't see any `--column-statistics=0` commented on that file

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with MySQL workbench latest edition, I resolved it using the mysqldump command line

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump --column-statistics=0  --user=USERNAME --host=REMOTE_HOST --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 DATABASE_NAME > c:\temp\dump.sql --password
```

Replace USERNAME, REMOTE_HOST, DATABASE_NAME with your names.

Answer (score 2):

On MACOS, just downgrade to version 8.0.13, that's the only thing did the job for us.

The following link can help

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

[image: MacOS MySQL Work Bench 8.0.13]

If you are using SSH key to access remote database then do the following -:

**Step 1**

```
brew install putty
```

**Step 2**

```
puttygen id_rsa -O private-openssh -o id_rsa.pem
```

**Step 3** - In MySQL workbench

```
SSH Key File: /Users/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pem
```

Hope it helps someone because it wasted 3 hours of our time :)

Answer (score 1):

in version 8, I modified "wb_admin_export.py" and restart workbench. works for me

```
def start(self):
.
.
.
    title = "Dumping " + schema
    title += " (%s)" % table
    # description, object_count, pipe_factory, extra_args, objects
    args = []
    args.append('--column-statistics=0')
```

````
class ViewsRoutinesEventsDumpData(DumpThread.TaskData):
    def __init__(self, schema, views, args, make_pipe):
        title = "Dumping " + schema + " views and/or routines and/or events"
        if not views:
           extra_args = ["--no-create-info"]
        else:
            extra_args = []
        DumpThread.TaskData.__init__(self,title, len(views), ["--skip-triggers", " --no-data" ," --no-create-db", "--column-statistics=0"] + extra_args + args, [schema] + views, None, make_pipe)```
````

Comment: this for MacOS wb_admin_export.py found @ /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can use native MySQL Workbench **"Migration wizard"** to migrate data without errors.
It can be found in menu
**Database -> Migration Wizard**
It can transfer data "online" but I didn't found an option to create a dump file with it.
It is a pretty good solution for migrations

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows with XAMPP, you need to indicate the path through XAMP. Do the following:

In your MySQL Workbench:
Go to `edit -> preferences -> administration` under "Path to mysqldump tool" enter the path: `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe`  then click ok.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded MySql Workbench to version 8.0.32 (Community Edition) and it solves the problem. It issues a warning, but performs the backup.