# How to disable column-statistics in MySQL 8 permanently?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

Since **MySQL 8** the `column-statistics` flag is enabled by default.

So if you try to dump some tables with **MySQL Workbench** 8.0.12, you get this error message:

> 14:50:22 Dumping db (table_name)
>   Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmpvu0mxn.cnf"  --user=db_user --host=db_host --protocol=tcp --port=1337 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "db_name" "table_name"
>   mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';': Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 2
>   14:50:24 Export of C:\path\to\my\dump has finished with 1 errors

Is there any way in MySQL (Workbench) 8 to disable `column-statistics` permanently?

---

### Workaround 1

An annoying workaround is doing it by hand via:

```
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --host=...
```

---

### Workaround 2

1. rename mysqldump
2. create a **shell script** (or batch on Windows)
3. call the renamed mysqldump with the `--column-statistics=0` argument within this script
4. save it as mysqldump

---

### Workaround 3

1. download **MySQL 5.7**
2. extract mysqldump
3. use this mysqldump

For example in MySQL Workbench: Edit / Preferences... / Administration / Path to mysqldump Tool

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you rename mysqldump, make a shell script in its place and call the renamed mysqldump with the --column-statistics=0 argument?

Comment: Just read about this other workaround. But is there no setting / no configuration for MySQL / MySQL Workbench?

Comment: i don't think so, i think the issue is that there is a compatibility issue with the mysqldump included with mysql 8, i have seen that some users are downloading mysql 5.7 and extracting the mysqldump and using that..

Comment: Yep, I've seen that as well, but I don't like this solution that much.
If there is no official / no clean way, I uninstall MySQL Workbench 8.0.12 and reinstall 6.3.10 - that would be too bad!

Comment: Workaround 3 worked like a charm.

Answer (score 37):

Workaround for me:

1. Create file named mysqldump.cmd with contents:

```
    @echo off
    "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe" %* --column-statistics=0
```

(replace path to mysqldump.exe if necessary)

2. Open MySQL Workbench and go to Edit > Preferences > Administration, change path to mysqldump tool and point it to mysqldump.cmd

Comment: this worked for me while using MySQL Workbench Version 8.0.15 build 14271522 CE (64 bits) with MySQL 5.7 db instance

Comment: This seems to be the only valid workaround as of 8.0.19, so thank you..

Comment: getting error 'Workbench was unable to get mysqldump version. Please verify the log for more information.' macOs

Comment: Worked for me on v8.0.26

Comment: getting error 'Workbench was unable to get mysqldump version. Please verify the log for more information.' on 8.0.25

Comment: it just crashes mysql workbench

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 with MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE (v8.0.30 build 2054668 CE 64-bit). I struggled with other solutions for about 20 minutes but this one worked with no issues.

Answer (score 19):

Easiest Work Around

When using **Mysql Workbench 8.0**

- Open the "Data Export" Tab
- Click Advanced Options  [image]
- Under the Other heading, set column statistics to 0   [image]
- Export again[image]

Best of luck!

Comment: Looks like in v8.0.14 they removed this option.

Comment: There is a bug report for this removal in v8.0.14 and v8.0.15: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94294
It will be reintroduced in v8.0.16.

Comment: this option is still not available on v8.0.16

Comment: Still not available in version 8.0.19

Comment: still not available 8.0.21. I don't know what MySQL team is doing at this point

Comment: I've found a workaround for adding it back to workbench. Check out this link. This is for mac, but maybe someone can figure out for windows as well. I now have that option back on 8.0.21 - https://serverfault.com/a/1015459

Comment: I was still on 8.0.13. Good to know I should not upgrade!

Comment: Still not available in version 8.0.23

Comment: Still not available in version 8.0.33 

Answer (score 9):

I have download the version 8.0.16, still the same issue.

At data export advanced options I didn't saw any option about "statistics"! 
I have add at my.ini at

```
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
column-statistics=0
```

Doesn't solve the issue

I have been googling but I couldn't find the solution. I find a of companions who are strugling with this but not anyone with the solution at least for me.

At the end I have changed at MySQL Workbench file c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_export.py:

```
skip_column_statistics = True #if get_mysqldump_version() > Version(8, 0, 2) and self.owner.ctrl_be.target_version < Version(8, 0, 0) else False
```

I have made comment of

```
if get_mysqldump...
```

I know this is not the way, but I can't find now another better solution. For me is this at least weird and strange. If anyone has a better solution let me know!

P.S. Restart Workbench after change has been made

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench Version 8.0.15 build 14271522 CE (64 bits) with MySQL 5.7 db instance, I could not find the lines skip_column_statistics... and if get_mysqldump... on the mentioned path of .py file

Answer (score 6):

The idea is this: each server version has a dedicated mysqldump version. Not ideal and certainly not very backwards compatible, but that's the situation. MySQL Workbench can only include one mysqldump binary, so the latest one is used. The approach to download the MySQL 5.7 zip and use mysqldump from there is a good workaround without many side effects. You only have to be careful which server you dump with which dump version.

If you like to have that column stat flag automatically applied by MySQL Workbench please file a bug report at https://bugs.mysql.com.

**Update**

Meanwhile a bug report has been created for this issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91640

Answer (score 5):

**WINDOWS USERS**

I have **MySQL Workbench 8.0CE and Xampp v3.2.3** and this worked for me:

1. Open xampp, and open mysql config > my.ini // add: column-statistics = 0 so:

```
    [mysqldump]
    quick
    max_allowed_packet = 16M
    column-statistics = 0
```

Save and close, reboot xampp mysql server. (just in case)

in Workbench:
**Edit > Preferences > Administration**

In Mysqldump route put your mysqldump route of xampp, in my case:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

There may be another workaround if you are running an OS that supports mysqldump (i.e. Linux). Set the path to the mysqldump binary in the preferences and include the --column-statistics=0 argument in the path, in:
Edit >> Preferences >> Administration >> path to MysqlDump Tool

Answer (score 3):

Mac user:

/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins
Update file wb_admin_export.py to skip_column_statistics in all cases.

```
skip_column_statistics = True # if get_mysqldump_version() > Version(8, 0, 2) and self.owner.ctrl_be.target_version < Version(8, 0, 0) else False
```

Answer (score 2):

From **Mysql-workbench version 8.0.14** you don't have the option to disable **column-statistics**.
But you have an option to do it by **enabling delete-master-logs:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855306/10747412

Comment: this options works for me on 8.0.21 workbench CE version

Answer (score 2):

Open MySQL Workbench Preferences and choose **Path to mysqldump Tool** accordiing to your xampp / mysql server path

MySQL Workbench Edit > Preferences > Administration

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe

that's it

Comment: Worked for me, MySQL Workbench 8.0.33 and Wampserver 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Download the last version of Mysql Workbench 8.0.16 and no more problems.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

No option to check !

Comment: Incorrect - I'm on 8.0.16 and it still fails. They haven't reintroduced the field they removed in 8.0.14

Comment: No need to downvote. I never told that the field was here. I had the same problem and now I can export without error

Comment: Agreed. I updated to 8.0.16 and I could export without any issues.

Comment: This worked for me. In fact when you do the export with 8.0.16, it AUTOMATICALLY specifies --column-statistics=0 in the command. BUT don't try to get 8.0.22, it's a nightmare trying to figure out the Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable prerequisites. I worked on that for an hour before I found this solution which didn't have those prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, MySql Workbench 6.3.6, MySql 8.0.25, MySqlDump 8.0.25.

My workaround is as follows:

1. Open **/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_export.py**
2. Replace

```
s = re.match(".*Distrib ([\d.a-z]+).*", output)
```

with

```
s = re.match(".*mysqldump  Ver ([\d.]+).*", output)
```

3. Replace

```
cmd = subprocess.list2cmdline(args)
```

with

```
args.append("--column-statistics=0")
cmd = subprocess.list2cmdline(args)
```

Comment: in version 8.0.29, step 2 is already there with an if condition like this `if ("Distrib" in output):` 

So I just utilized step 3 and it's now working.

Comment: I installed it thru a snap and not even `chmod` can give me write access to this file. The APT installation fails for Workbench 8.0.x on Ubuntu 22.04. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

##### Linux users

Same idea as [the other answer above on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745458/11154841), here is a way to globally change the mysql settings **on Linux** so that you do not need to write `mysqldump --column-statistics=0` anymore.

Quote from Server Fault Stack Exchange at [mysqldump throws: Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)](https://serverfault.com/a/912677/607547), highly upvoted there:

> To disable column statistics by default, you can add
>
> ```
> [mysqldump]
> column-statistics=0
> ```
>
> to a MySQL config file. Go to `/etc/my.cnf`, `~/.my.cnf`, or directly
> to `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

I recommend changing it directly in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

Comment: Sadly this does not work on Linux either if Workbench was installed thru a snap.

Comment: @JoachimRives It is too long ago now, I cannot say for sure whether I tested this answer, but I used DBeaver with snap installation. If it ever worked like this, perhaps change to DBeaver. No guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by amending the MySQL Workbench config file `wb_admin_export.py`.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803608/cant-export-my-database-from-mysql-workbench/59982834#59982834).

Answer (score 0):

[![Export From DBEAVER with extra command][1]][1]

For me, I just added an extra command and it worked for me!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iBvO.png