# MySQL Workbench Unable to export data

Tags: mysql, workbench

When trying to export a large database I am getting this error message:

```
13:16:10 Dumping interlog_isems (all tables)
Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpo5nj8c.cnf"  --user=interlog_isems --host=103.52.144.133 --protocol=tcp --port=3307 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "interlog_isems"
mysqldump: Error: 'The foreign data source you are trying to reference does not exist. Data source error:  error: 1146  'Table 'tmi_inv.fedTransfer3' doesn't exist'' when trying to dump tablespaces
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'interlog_isems' AND TABLE_NAME = 'VW_Device';': Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109)

Operation failed with exitcode 2
13:16:12 Export of C:\Users\Admin\Documents\dumps\interlog_isems.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

Any clue why?  And what should I do to successfully export the table from online to offline.  I would like to download the sql on my local from the web server.

In this case, I am using mysql workbench to export the sql from online.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Workbench are you using

Answer (score 0):

**Mysql-workbench** from version 8.0.14 disable the option to **disable column-statistics** but you can do it with a newer version of MySQL-workbench by following this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855306/10747412