# How do I modify the mysqldump command arguments in MySQL Workbench 8.0.14?

Tags: mysql, windows-10, export, mysql-workbench

I'm experiencing the same problem in MySQL Workbench 8.0.14 as the following post:
[Can't export my database from mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803608/cant-export-my-database-from-mysql-workbench)

However, I don't have the `Other/column-statistics` option noted in the answers. Apparently though, I can add the `--column-statistics=0` argument to the `mysqldump` command being executed to fix the problem.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to do that in Windows 10. How do I modify the execution of the `mysqldump` command, either via MySQL Workbench or some other means, to add the `--column-statistics=0` argument when it's executed? Thank you.

---

**Edit**: For what it's worth, as I think about this more, I'm wondering if I can't do anything about this problem because I'm trying to export from an external DB that the user I'm using may not have full access to and I'm having to use an SSH tunnel to even access the DB. I'm going to try installing a different version of MySQL Workbench and seeing if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have MySQL Workbench 8.0.13, and I do have the option mentioned:

[image]

Okay I just upgraded to Workbench 8.0.14, and I see that the option has vanished. I have no idea why they did that, unless they want to make it harder to use Workbench with older versions of MySQL. That seems shortsighted.

I added a comment to the bug related to this issue (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91640), to note that the option has disappeared.

It was weird that the option was a text field instead of a checkbox like other options on the same screen. Maybe it disappeared in 8.0.14 because the code was not implemented correctly.

---

If you use mysqldump at the command-line, you can use `--skip-column-statistics`

Comment: After spending no less than two hours playing around with various things trying to figure this out, uninstalling MySQL Workbench 8.0.14 and installing MySQL Workbench 8.0.13 and then setting `0` for the option now available solved my problem. Thanks, Bill.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench 8.0.14+ comes with a checkbox to allow switching this setting:

[image]

However, this option is only shown when the used mysqldump version supports it (remember you can use a different mysqldump binary than the one bundled with Workbench, by setting it in the preferences). If unsupported you will get an entry in your WB log like:

> 09:49:52 [DB1][wb_admin_export.py:**init**:2044]: Skip option column-statistics because it's for mysqldump 8.0.2

Installing different mysqldump versions can be done either with a MySQL Installer for Windows (that ships the server version in question) or by manually downloading the server msi and installing that. The mysqldump tool is part of each server package. Then open the MySQL Workbench preferences and select the new binary in `Administration -> Path to mysqldump tool`:

[image]

Comment: How do you install multiple versions of mysqldump in Windows 10 and then point to one or the other? Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot.